# QML: Change cursor color in TextField

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

How to change cursor color and probably width in QML `TextField` element? Let say we have following one:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

TextField {
    id: control
    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 40
        color: control.enabled ? "transparent" : "#353637"
        border.color: control.enabled ? "#21be2b" : "transparent"
    }
}
```

How to make cursor color green or blue or whatever? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to set Rectangle with the color you want as the cursor through the [`cursorDelegate`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#cursorDelegate-prop) since [`TextField`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qml-qtquick-controls2-textfield.html) inherits from [`TextInput`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qml-qtquick-textinput.html) and therefore shares that property.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

TextField {
    id: control
    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")
    cursorDelegate: Rectangle {
        visible: control.cursorVisible
        color: "salmon"
        width: control.cursorRectangle.width
    }
    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 40
        color: control.enabled ? "transparent" : "#353637"
        border.color: control.enabled ? "#21be2b" : "transparent"
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, missed that in documentation. Thanks much! Work just fine!

Answer (score 7):

@eyllanesc provides a very good answer, but I want to point that the blinking behavior will not be preserved when you define a custom `cursorDelegate`.

If you want to have the blinking of the cursor. It can be done using an animation:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

TextField {
    id: control
    placeholderText: qsTr("Enter description")

    background: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 40
        color: control.enabled ? "transparent" : "#353637"
        border.color: control.enabled ? "#21be2b" : "transparent"
    }

    cursorDelegate: Rectangle {
        id: cursor
        visible: false
        color: "salmon"
        width: control.cursorRectangle.width

        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            running: control.cursorVisible

            PropertyAction {
                target: cursor
                property: 'visible'
                value: true
            }

            PauseAnimation {
                duration: 600
            }

            PropertyAction {
                target: cursor
                property: 'visible'
                value: false
            }

            PauseAnimation {
                duration: 600
            }

            onStopped: {
                cursor.visible = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right! Good addition, thanks!