# How can I set the blue pin cursor invisible in TextField qml?

Tags: android, qt, qml, textfield

I am writing Qt for the Android app. I didn't see this blue pin cursor in Qt 5, but when I migrated to Qt 6, this pin appeared, I read ([the doc from Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#echoMode-prop)) but no description found for this pin cursor. Any idea would be appreciated!
[image]

I tried to use the cursorDelegate to customize this, but it turns out that the cursorDelegate can only be applied to that vertical line cursor. I also read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58719796/qml-change-cursor-color-in-textfield) but like I said, the cursorDelegate only controls the vertical line cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You may be affected by the changes to [Styles in Qt Quick Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-styles.html#available-styles) in Qt6:

If no style is explicitly set, a default style will be used. The default style used depends on the operating system:

- Android: Material Style
- iOS: iOS Style
- Linux: Fusion Style
- macOS: macOS Style
- Windows: Windows Style

If you want to change the default style, you can control it via [Qt Quick Controls Configuration File](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-configuration.html), e.g. the following uses the `qtquickcontrols2.conf` file to change the default style to `Universal`:

```
[Controls]
Style=Universal
```

In order to make it possible for Qt Quick Controls to find the configuration file, it must be built into application's resources using the [The Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/resources.html). Here's an example .qrc file:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>qtquickcontrols2.conf</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```